# Сумма полей класса C++

Tags: c++, классы

У меня есть класс salon с полем car ; как найти сумму всех car, если я не знаю сколько будет обьектов изначально?

```
class salon
{
 int car;
 public :
 //////какие то функции
 }



int main()
salon s1;
salon s2;
salon s3;


//// сумма s1.car +s2.car + s3.car .. +sn.car
```

Comment: в вашем случае вы не сможете обратиться к car, т.к при таком объявлении он будет считаться private членом.

Comment: Интересно бы послушать ваше решение, если вы знаете изначально количество объектов... :)

Comment: Если кол-во слагаемых вам неизвестно, как вы получите их сумму?

Answer (score 6):

Введите в класс статическую переменную `static unsigned int NCar;` сразу вслед за декларацией класса: `NCar = 0;` а в конструкторе или в функции, где определяется число автомобилей в салоне: `NCar += car`.

Comment: Надо не забыть уменьшать в деструкторе, и позаботиться о копирующем конструкторе и операторе присваивания. Для полного счастья. Но вопрос, на самом деле, не достаточно ясен в текущем виде.

Answer (score 3):

использовать динамический массив, или вектор, и по итератору пробегаться по полям как-то так

```
vector<salon> salons;
vector<salon>::iterator itSalon;
//заполняешь вектор
int cars = 0;
for(itSalon = salons.begin(); itSalon != salons.end(); ++itSalon)
{
    cars += itSalon->car;
}
```

Comment: При вычислении суммы в том или ином виде рекомендуется использовать алгоритм `std::accumulate` вместо ручного создания цикла.